# Is there a way to check if virtualisation is enabled on the BIOS using C++?

Tags: c++, x86-64, virtualization

I'm trying to check if virtualisation (AMD-V or Intel VT) is enabled programmatically. I know the bash [commands](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-xen-vmware-kvm-intel-vt-amd-v-support/) that gives you this information but I'm trying to achieve this in C++.

On that note, I'm trying to avoid using `std::system` to execute shell code because of how hacky and unoptimal that solution is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many linux tools are open source.  Take a look at the code for the one that looks for virtualization and see what it does.

Comment: If you're allowed to use operating system features then please say which operating system.

Comment: If you have a working bash script that you're trying to port / replicate in C++, include the bash-script version.

Comment: Just in case, you understand that pressing a checkmark next to an answer indicates you don't need any more help, right?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yeah, I'm just going to pipe some shell commands instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if VMX or SVM (Intel and AMD virtualization technologies) are enabled you need to use the `cpuid` instruction.

This instruction comes up so often in similar tests that the mainstream compilers all have an intrinsic for it, you don't need inline assembly.

For Intel's CPUs you have to check `CPUID.1.ecx[5]`, while for AMD's ones you have to check `CPUID.1.ecx[2]`.

Here's an example. I only have gcc on an Intel CPU, **you are required to properly test and fix this code for other compilers and AMD CPUs**.

The principles I followed are:

1. Unsupported compilers and non-x86 architecture should fail to compile the code.
2. If run on an x86 compatible CPU that is neither Intel nor AMD, the function return `false`.

The code assumes `cpuid` exists, for Intel's CPUs this is true since the 486. The code is designed so that `cpuid_ex` can return `false` to denote that `cpuid` is not present, but *I didn't implement a test for it* because that would require inline assembly. GCC and clang have a built-in for this but MSVCC doesn't.

Note that if you only build 64-bit binaries you always have `cpuid`, you can remove the 32-bit architecture check so that if someday somebody tries to use a 32-bit build, the code fails to compile.

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <intrin.h>
#elif defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__)
#include <cpuid.h>
#endif

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

//Execute cpuid with leaf "leaf" and given the temporary array x holding the
//values of eax, ebx, ecx and edx (after cpuid), copy x[start:end) into regs
//converting each item in a uint32_t value (so this interface is the same even
//for esoteric ILP64 compilers).
//If CPUID is not supported, returns false (NOTE: this check is not done, CPUID
//exists since the 486, it's up to you to implement a test. GCC & CLANG have a
//nice macro for this. MSVCC doesn't. ICC I don't know.)
bool cpuid_ex(unsigned int leaf, uint32_t* regs, size_t start = 0, size_t end = 4)
{
#if ( ! defined(__x86_64__) && ! defined(__i386__) && ! defined(_M_IX86) && ! defined(_M_X64))
    //Not an x86
    return false;
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
    //MS & Intel
    int x[4]
    __cpuid((int*)x, leaf); 
#elif defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__)
    //GCC & clang
    unsigned int x[4];
    __cpuid(leaf, x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]);
#else
    //Unknown compiler
    static_assert(false, "cpuid_ex: compiler is not supported");
#endif
    //Conversion from x[i] to uint32_t is safe since GP registers are 32-bit at least
    //if we are using cpuid
    for (; start < end; start++)
        *regs++ = static_cast<uint32_t>(x[start]);
        
    return true;
}

//Check for Intel and AMD virtualization.
bool support_virtualization()
{
    //Get the signature
    uint32_t signature_reg[3] = {0};
    if ( ! cpuid_ex(0, signature_reg, 1))
        //cpuid is not supported, this returns false but you may want to throw
        return false;

    uint32_t features;
    //Get the features
    cpuid_ex(1, &features, 2, 3);
    
    //Is intel? Check bit5
    if (signature_reg[0] == 0x756e6547 && signature_reg[1] == 0x6c65746e && signature_reg[2] == 0x49656e69)
        return features & 0x20;
    
    //Is AMD? check bit2
    if (signature_reg[0] == 0x68747541 && signature_reg[1] == 0x69746e65 && signature_reg[2] == 0x444d4163)
        return features & 0x04; 
    
    //Not intel or AMD, this returns false but you may want to throw
    return false;
}
    


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Virtualization is " << (support_virtualization() ? "": "NOT ") << "supported\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to detect virtualization support using only standard C++ facilities. The C++ standard library does not have anything related to hardware virtualization. (Its exposure of low level details like that is extremely limited.)

You would need to use OS-specific facilities to detect this.

Comment: This is technically correct, but OP didn't say they're limited to the standard c++.